# What config files I need to verify to make sudo work?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, security, sudo

I am new to Linux. I have created 2 Azure VMs based on Cent OS 7.4 for learning purposes. For the first machine, I provided SSH keys during the create procedure. I use the private key via putty and login to the box. For the second box, I provided password and use this for logging in. Everything works as expected on the second box as well. Now to change it, I added the SSH keys for the second box as well. But whenever I run a command with "sudo", the second box asks for password where as first one does not (obviously I never provided password for it and works as expected). I have verified sudoers file, sshd_config file, bashrc and other files. They all match. What other config file I need to verify to see the differences between the machines?
The other question is If I have to add a password for first machine, what config files I need to be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sudo` command is configured by the file `/etc/sudoers`, which, in CentOS 7, also includes all config files under the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory. Some `cloudinit` script will add the main/first created user to the `wheel` group and enable the option

```
%wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

for passwordless commands for any user in the `wheel` group.

Check your user ID and group IDs with the `id` command, and see if there is any reference to it/them in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory or the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: Thanks. I had checked the wheel group. I had set wheel group to use the password. So I knew that was not the answer. The hint was sudoers.d directory. There is a reference to my user id with NOPASSWD:ALL. Your help is greatly appreciated.